# Non diverse Global Secondary Index in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's assume that I have a table with following attributes:

- UNIQUE `user_id` (primary hash key)
- `category_id` (GSI hash index)
- `timestamp`

I will have a lot of users, but only few categories.

```
user_id  |  category_id
1           1
3           1
4           1
5           3
..          ..
50000000    1
```

Is it ok to store millions of records with the same `category_id` value as a Global Secondary Index? Should I expect any restrictions?

I'm wondering if scan is not a bad choice. I will use filtering by `category_id` only once a day. What is the cost (time and money) of scanning millions of records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) documentation, the only limitation is:

> No practical limit for tables without local secondary indexes.
>
> For a table with local secondary indexes, there is a limit on item collection sizes: For every distinct hash key value, the total sizes of all table and index items cannot exceed 10 GB. Depending on your item sizes, this may constrain the number of range keys per hash value. For more information, see Item Collection Size Limit.

Now for your second question of whether you should be doing Query or Scan, you asked both from performance and monetary cost. Maintaining a GSI is expensive, because you have to pay for the throughput (and if I recall correctly also the storage) so its like paying for another table, plus its another table whose throughput you have to monitor to make sure you aren't being throttled. On the other hand, the performance is much better.

If you're planning on going through all categories once a day (which means every Document in the Table), then Scan is the way to go. You aren't gaining anything from Querying. Plus its cheaper (no extra GSI) and you don't have to worry about projections.

Comment: "No practical limit for tables without local secondary indexes." - but I'm talking about Global Secondary Index :-) .. "then Scan is the way to go." - but scanning of 50 000 000 of records and getting only Count(*) will cost something?

Comment: If you're just trying to get Count of 50 million records, then a Dynamo Scan or even Query isn't the best way to go. You're better off keeping a separate counter. Perhaps a separate Dynamo table where you have one document per type and you Increment and Decrement there when you do write to the main table.